# Eclipse autosave workspace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a plugin for Eclipse which would automatically save the eclipse workspace every say 5 minutes in the background because every time eclipse crashes the entire workspace layout reverts or open files gets lost, and it is quite annoying at this point.

Comment: ... and if it crashes because of the workspace configuration?

Comment: Too bad there isn't a suitable solution for this yet. Whenever my laptop crashes when coming out of standby or when it's battery is empty I have to reopen all the files I had open previously.

Comment: It's old, not helpful anymore. I don't even have the necessary environment anymore to be able to accept any answers.

Answer (score 3):

Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace
There is a box for the "Workspace save interval". But I am not sure that this is the thing you're looking for.

Comment: Based on my experiences with Eclipse crashes losing my workspace, I don't think this will do it.

Comment: This does not work, always been every 5 minutes but there were no workspace saves done ever except on exit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a plugin ["Smart Save"](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/smart-save#.UiGaK9-SazB).

Comment: I have "Luna" and wonder why "Smart Save" is not included with it. Anyway, smart save is good, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To save the layout, just change everything the way you like and then restart. Eclipse won't corrupt its prefs after a crash, so this should work. As an additional step, you can save the current perspective under a different name and export the prefs to a file. You can then load this file in case of a disaster.

I don't have a solution for the lost files issue, though.

Comment: It sounds like this is the exact opposite of the solution the OP is looking for. He wants to save his workspace without having to close Eclipse.

Comment: /agree with Bears will eat you. Aside from not restarting I don't want to restart eclipse every time I open a file either so I don't have to re-open everything, etc. The layout is the least of my problems as I obviously already am in the habit of do layout, restart, because of this issue. Its just annoying to have to go from scratch every time eclipse crashes (1-2 times per day)

Comment: You just have to do this once. As I said, I have no solution for "keep files open" but closing eclipse once will at least preserve the layout of the perspectives.

Answer (score 0):

[This Eclipse bug entry](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=337593) references the [saveuistate plugin](http://eclipsenuggets.blogspot.com/2007/09/how-to-save-eclipse-ui-workbench-state_6644.html) which is supposed to autosave the workspace state *if changed* every 5 minutes or after every build.  **Note**:  the aforementioned bug entry states that you must alter the plugin's MANIFEST.MF file to bump the supported Eclipse version numbers...

I haven't tried it yet but it sounds like this is exactly what the OP wanted.

I'll be trying it soon because I have the same issue -- when my VirtualBox Ubuntu guest environment crashes (it *does* happen...) I have to re-open my previously open files/tabs... *sigh*...